# Use of Quotes in Form Element values

Tags: html, forms, http-post

I have created a `Textarea` control. The data entered in this control goes to a `database` when Submit is clicked. However, when the user types single quotes while entering value in this control and clicks Submit, data does not go to the database.

How can I allow users to enter special characters like this while entering data in the form?

Comment: can u show the code that insert to db

Answer (score 0):

When inserting data in a query, you have to escape them with `mysql_real_escape_string()` (if mysql database). This protects you from [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(col) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."')");
```

When showing data in form elements, you have to escape them like this with `htmlspecialchars()` function. This protects you from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this code. Thanks for the information.